# SQLAlchemy Multiple Inheritance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, sqlalchemy, polygon

I am having trouble with multiple inheritance in SQLAlchemy. I have read that it is possible, but haven't been able to find any good examples.

I would like to model my data as follows:

```
- Layer   

    - VaporLayer

    - SolutionLayer
       - OrganicLayer
       - AqueousLayer
```

When I query these models in a python shell I get inconsistent results. If I query `Layer` first, I get blank objects which only have an `id` field and a blank `layer_type` field for all subsequent queries of any model in this hierarchy. If I query `SolutionLayer` in a new shell, I get instances of `OrganicLayer` and `AqueousLayer` (which have the correct `layer_type` and `solution_layer_type` fields) even when I query `Layer`. I have tried to adapt the with_polymorphic function unsuccessfully yielding the same results. Ideally, these queries would always yield the most specific Class (farthest down hierarchy) or at least consistently have populated `layer_type`

The following matches my models.py:

```
class Layer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "layers"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    layer_volume = Column(Float)
    layer_type = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "layers",
        "polymorphic_on": layer_type,
    }


class VaporLayer(Layer):
    __tablenema__ = "vapor_layers"
    id = Column(ForeignKey("layers.id"), primary_key=True)
    voltage = Column(Float)
    pressure = Column(Float)
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity":'vapor_layers'}


class SolutionLayer(Layer):
    __tablename__ = "solution_layers"
    id = Column(ForeignKey("layers.id"), primary_key=True)

    spin_speed = Column(Integer)
    spin_duration = Column(Float)
    spin_temp = Column(Float)
    solution_layer_type = Column(String)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "solution_layers",
        "polymorphic_on": solution_layer_type,
    }


class OrganicLayer(SolutionLayer):
    __tablename__ = "organic_layers"
    id = Column(ForeignKey("solution_layers.id"), primary_key=True)

    organic_solute = Column(String)
    organic_solvent = Column(String)
    concentration = Column(Float)

    additive = Column(String)
    additive_concentration = Column(Float)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "organic_layers",
    }


class AqueousLayer(SolutionLayer):
    __tablename__ = "aqueous_layers"
    id = Column(ForeignKey("solution_layers.id"), primary_key=True)
    solute = Column(String)
    solute_concentration = Column(String)
    solute_batch = Column(String)

    additive = Column(String)
    additive_concentration = Column(Float)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "aqueous_layers",
    }
```

Comment: I based my model off of how I Interpreted the [joined table inheritance](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/_modules/examples/inheritance/joined.html) example in the documentation

Comment: After quite a bit of trial and error I see that I should not have added `"polymorphic_on"` to `__mapper_args__` in the SolutionLayer class. This was overwriting the `Layer.layer_type`. Functionality now appears to be as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `"polymorphic_on"` to `__mapper_args__` in the SolutionLayer class appears to overwrite `Layer.layer_type` and preventing the ORM from determining what class the object actually is. Working now with that removal.